# Sharing a variable across packages in java

Tags: java, file, variables, package

I wanted a common variable to be accessed from two files present in 2different packages in Java. Suppose variable name is x present in file1 and file2 belonging to package1 and package2 respectively.

I tried declaring variable x as public static and initialised it to 0. So whenever value of x is changed in suppose file2, then in file1 at that line of code where x  variable is encountered, the updated value should be reflected (updated value means the value the variable x is updated with in the file2). This is not working for me. Instead of getting updated value, debugger is hitting the point where x variable is declared and initialised to 0. So the updated value is lost for me.

So in general, whether variable x is updated in file1 or file2, the value of x should get updated accordingly when that line of code is hit in respective files.

Please provide a solution for this.

Hope the question is clear and I am new to java.
Edit:
Here in both the files I have to set a value to variable and be able to get the value of that variable. While I try to access it in file2 after x being modified in file1, x doesn't show the updated value. What is happening is that it calls "public static int x=0" whenever it encounters the variable x in file2 and then it does my functionality(my logic on x). So, I'm getting wrong value

Comment: Do not repeat yourself.  Just code it in one place and then call that common method from both places.  It can be a static method if you want.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and then update your question to show some code. With only the description it's hard to understand what you are trying to do and where your error is. What you are describing definitely _is_ possible so you seem to have either a misconception of how things work or some error in your code.

Comment: What you're asking should be trivial to solve if we can see your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem completely but try this code:

```
package package1;

import package2.Class2;

public class Class1 {
    
    public static int x = 0;
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Class1.x);
        Class2.printX();
        x = 5;
        System.out.println(Class1.x);
        Class2.printX();
        
        
    }

}

package package2;

    import package1.Class1;
    
    public class Class2 {
    
        public static void printX() {
            System.out.println(Class1.x);
        }
    
    }
```

That way Class2 refers to Class1.x and should produce correct results